# Two past tense verbs adjacent to each other

Tags: phrases

Is it possible to have two verbs next to each other without any punctuation?

For example, would a punctuation be required between faced and fortified?

...hearing about the challenges they faced fortified my interest in xxx.

Comment: Please be aware that a general request for improvements to a sentence falls into the category of "writing advice" or of "proofreading," neither of which is on-topic at this website. On-topic at this site are questions about why a specific phrase is ungrammatical or problematic as a matter of usage.

Comment: Definitely not if it means that the comma would come between the subject and the verb, as it would in your example. In other instances, it depends on the particular construction such as whether the clause that the verb introduces is integrated into clause structure or supplementary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't adjacent verbs. The following sentence requires no comma:

> Hearing about the challenges they **faced was** a factor in fortifying my interest.

The problem is what the *Chicago Manual of Style* calls a mistaken junction and what others call a garden path -- i.e., a placement of words that leads the reader into a mistaken parse. When a reader encounters

> they faced fortified

he may well expect the sentence to continue as

> they **faced fortified** battlements.

His expectations will be dashed as *fortified* is a finite verb in your sentence and not a participial modifier. Following the gerund clause with a comma will prevent the erroneous parse:

> Hearing about the challenges they **faced, fortified** my interest.

But as a general rule, style manuals recommend against using a comma to separate subjects (here, the gerund clause with *Hearing*) from their predicates (here, *fortified my interest*). In this case, doing so simply creates another garden path, leading the hapless reader to at first consider that the gerund clause is an absolute and thus expecting

> hearing about the challenges they faced, I was fortified in my interest.

Alas, punctuation can only get you so far, and in this case into further trouble. Consider rewriting your way out of this conundrum along the lines of

> My interest was fortified by hearing about the challenges they faced.